# Detecting Guild ID

Tags: discord.js

I want to make certain commands so they can only be used in a specific guild.

I've tried an if statement that checks if message.guild.id = the guild id, but the command still will execute in any guild, perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

```
client.on("message", msg => {

  var bcid = "585676550544949248"
  if (msg.guild.id = bcid) {

    if (msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + "ping")) {
      msg.channel.send("Pong! :ping_pong:");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One `=` symbol is used for assigning a value to a variable, two `==` or three `=` symbols are used for checking if a value equals another value. In `if` statements you use the two or thee equals symbol operator.

Thus to fix your problem, change the `if` to:

```js
if (msg.guild.id === bcid) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Check out [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) to learn about the difference between `==` and `===`.

Comment: To elaborate, the reason why the current `if` statement works is because it's setting the variable each time the event is emitted. It's then returning truthy, and the code inside of the block is being executed. ([Assignment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators); [equality operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_operators))